# Cohomology of Finitely Generated Ideal Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I have a question about a step in following proof gived in Badescu's "Algebraic Surfaces":

[image]

I the given setting by assumption the ideal sheaf $I$ is finitely generated therefore there exist following short ex sequence of sheaves:

$$0 \to K \to O_X^m \to I \to O$$

with $K$ kernel of right map.

My question why the second sheaf cohomology group $H^2(K)$ vanish?

Comment: Should your short exact sequence be $0 \to K \to O_X^m \to I \to 0$ or am I missing something?

Comment: @mathphys: yes of course :) Thank you

Comment: Also, what is $H^2(K)$? Presumably it's not the sheaf cohomology because the notation $H^2(X, K)$ is not used, so is it the second cohomology of a resolution of $K$ perhaps?

Comment: here indeed $H^2(K) = H^2(X,K)$ the sheaf coho is meant. The author just wanted just to abbreviate it

Comment: by the way $H^2(X,K)$ arises from a injective resultion $K \to I^{\bullet}$ (after applying $\Gamma(-,X)=H^0(-,X)$) by definition since the category of sheaves over $X$ have enough injectives

Comment: Indeed it does, but I was confused as to whether the abbreviation meant the sheaf cohomology or higher direct image of a pushforward as at the start of the question.

Comment: I see what you mean. at the start of the question the author just wanted to point you that $R^1f_*O_X$ = $\overline{H^1(O_X)}$ (in sense of sheafification of presheaf $U \to H^1(f^{-1}(U),O_X)$)  vanish. Yes, set theoretically this "equality" is confusing. But in the line where my problem arises it seems that he uses $H^1(X, K)$ since the sequence at my ? is a part of the long exact seqence induced by $0 \to K \to O_X^m \to I \to O$

Comment: ...in this sense: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheaf_cohomology#Definition

Comment: Because $Y$ is affine and thus coherent sheaves has no higher cohomology and $f$ is proper with relative dimension 1, so $R^pf_*\mathcal{F}$ is coherent and vanishes for $p>1$. It follows (for example with the Leray-spectral sequence) that $H^p(X,\mathcal{F})=0$ for any $p>1$ and any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: @Roland: You mean the seven-term-sequence as a derivate of Leray-spectral sequence, right? Using notation from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-term_exact_sequence and the identification $E_2^{p,q}= H^p(Y, R^q f_*F)$ the seven-term sequence gives:

$$0 \to H^1(Y, f_*F) \to H^1(X, F) \to H^0(Y, R^1f_* F) \to H^2(Y, f_*F) \to Ker(H^2(X, F)\to H^0(Y, R^2f_* F)) \to H^1(Y, R^1 f_* F) \to H^3(Y, f_*F)$$

Comment: Then $H^i(Y, f_*F)=0$ for $i>0$ since $Y$ affine and $f_*F$ coherent (?) and $Ker(H^2(X, F)\to H^0(Y, R^2f_* F))= H^2(X, F)$ since $H^0(Y, R^2f_* F)=0$ by your observation that $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ vanishes for $i >1$. 

The world would be nice if we would know that $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ is also ***coherent*** for $i=0,1$.

Comment: The problem is that I know how it works if $f$ is finite morphism (then this is a local problem to show that for a $R$-algebra $A$ and a coherent $A$ module $M$ then restriction of $M$ to $R$ is also coherent: this is clear by composition of surjective maps $R^{nm} \to A^m \to M$ by finiteness of $f$. 

But here $f$ is not ***finite***. Why is $R^if_*\mathcal{F}$ nevertheless coherent sheaf?

Comment: No I meant the spectral sequence $E_ 2^{pq}=H^p(Y,R^qf_*\mathcal{F})\Rightarrow H^{p+q}(X,\mathcal{F})$. Note that $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ if $q>1$ and $H^p=0$ if $p>0$ so there is no $H^2$ (if $p+q=2$ then either $p>0$ or $q>1$).

Comment: The fact that if $f$ is proper then the higher direct image are coherent is a non trivial fact but find in any book (a sheafy version of the fact that coherent cohomology of a proper scheme is finitely generated).

Comment: ...and the fact that $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ for $q>1$ is the (blabla-I-don't-know-it's  name-thm) that $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}_y= \varprojlim_{Z_n} H^q(Z_n, \mathcal{F} \times O_{Z_n})$ with $Supp(Z_n)=f^{-1}(y)$? Or is the argument that $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ for $q>1$ a more general principle? (since for the former statement you need normality of $Y$; of course in our case it is given but I was just curious if $R^qf_*\mathcal{F}=0$ also holds under weaker condition: maybe ***only*** if the fiber of $y$ has dimension $\le 1$ and no additional condition